# Using guard with multiple types

Tags: ios, swift

I'm getting data from a server and one of the values can either be an `NSDictionary` or `[NSDictionary]`. I was wondering if it was possible to use the new Swift `guard` to check for both types. This is what I am doing right now:

```
guard let list = response["answer"] as? [NSDictionary] else {
    return nil
}
```

But I want something like this:

```
guard let list = response["answer"] as? [NSDictionary] || let list = response["answer"] as? NSDictionary else {
    return nil
}
```

I don't want to use `if-let`, because I really like the new syntax. Is there any way to achieve this with `guard` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend to separate the checks for availability and type.

First check if the key exists at all

```
  guard let list : AnyObject = response["answer"] else {
    return nil
  }
```

Then check the type

```
if list is NSDictionary {
  print("is dictionary")
} else if list is [NSDictionary] {
  print("is array of dictionary")
} else {
  fatalError("that should never happen")
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the keyword is to know the type (https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TypeCasting.html checking type )

edit : test that in a playground

```
var names: [String] = ["name 1" , "foo" , "Hotline Bling"   ,"vaudoo chills"]


func castingIs (sender : AnyObject) -> Bool {
    guard sender is String || sender is [String] else {
        return false
    }
    return true
}

castingIs(names) // true
castingIs(names[0]) // true
castingIs(4) // false
```